Gradual light transition
I have a hdr timelapse that combines images shot with 5ev3 brackets and 3ev3 brackets. because of this there is visible light transition in the middle of the video. What would be the easiest way to fix this and make it gradual? I already tried deflicker plugins, but it doesn't help. Video example is on this link: 


UPDATE
Leaving here my solution for this problem:
In case when you transition from 3HDR images to 1Image
I managed to do this in a pretty simple way and the result also seems to be pretty good. Since each HDR has 3 images (0ev, -3ev and +3ev), i just took out from the last 24 HDR image sequence images with 0ev ONLY, and created new clip only from those. Then I did opacity transition for these 24 images from 0% (image 1) to 100% (image 24). Then I overlayed this sequence in the video at the exactly same time that those HDR frames appear. Result - perfect gradual transition!
In case that transition is from 5HDR to 3HDR, same thing - just take 3hdr images instead of 1.

Easiest way:
Overlap the two videos slightly and crossfade.
Slightly trickier:
Animate feathered masks across them to make the transitions more subtle - easiest in After Effects
Another option:
Try to match the colour in the last frame of sequence 1 and the first frame of sequence 2 in a colour grading plugin (e.g. using Lumetri in Premiere)
LR Timelapse might also have options that help with this.

I think first 2 options would be noticeable since it would interrupt the flow? I will check more the  lumetri as you said - that one seems to be what I need here. thanks.

Given that it's a locked off shot, you'd be amazed what you can get away with. But it would reduce the overall duration obviously
